# PHP simulating a click on a div when the page loads

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to simulate a click on a div when the page loads and detects a 'settings' in the url using php.
How come this does not work?

```
if(isset($_GET['settings'])){ ?>
       <script>
           $(function(){
              $('#3').trigger("click"); //tried .click();
           });
        </script>
<?php }
```

Comment: $('#3') ??
what is this?? Is that your ID?

Comment: It's probably because jquery is not loaded when the `<script>` tag is executed.

Comment: yes, i am using it to identify what slider to trigger <div class="slide" id="3">

Comment: Ids shouldn't start with numbers.

Comment: why is the <script> not executed? and I will fix the id thing

Comment: No, you misread what I said.

Comment: sorry yeah, my jquery is at the footer.. that makes sense now.

Comment: Add this to the top of your `<script>` tag: `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  alert("jQuery is not loaded"); }`

Comment: This is probably being triggered before the page loads. Try adding it within a $(document).ready(function(){}

Comment: @RussellBevan That would imply jquery has been loaded though.

Comment: Yes, but the object may not be loaded

Comment: @RussellBevan That's my point. So putting `$(document).ready(function(){}` would not work because jQuery hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: i put the coe at the bottom of the page so it's after jquery-1.11.0.min.js and still it's not working

Comment: jQuery may be loaded, but whatever `#3` is may not be. The other issue is that the ID starts with a number which is invalid.

Comment: Also, what is the "click" event supposed to do?

Comment: it supposed to click on that div and the div will slide out content. how come the #3 works for identifying which slider as i have 6 of them?

Comment: add an alert() inside your function and see if it pops up when you load the page. Also, where is the code for your click event?

Comment: I think the problem is he triggered click before define it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric IDs are invalid in Jquery.

For more info **[Goto this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)**

```
ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

So try to use `$('.slide').trigger("click");`  instead of `$('#3').trigger("click");` or put some valid id and select using that.

Using this code will solve your problem

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Click </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slide">Show Target</div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="target">Target</div>
    <div class="hide-target">Hide Target</div>
<?php
    $_GET['settings'] = "some value";
    if(isset($_GET['settings'])){
?>      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.slide').click(function(){
                    alert("hi");
                    $(".target").show();
                });
                $('.hide-target').click(function(){
                    $(".target").hide();
                });
                $('.slide').trigger("click");
            });
        </script>
<?php
    }
?>    
</body>
```

Comment: i get the alert but the div won't slide out like it suppose to when i manually click it

Comment: the alert worked. the div (#3 in this case) once clicked, supposed to slide out .target i tried toggeling it but it didn't work

Comment: It was not in your question. U said just to alert. U have to post your rest of the code. Then only I can help you.

Comment: This is the code <div class="slide" id="3"></div><div class="target">text..</div>

Comment: Then whats your exact requirement? what is to be happen to this divs?